# how to use XSP.fireEvent?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

> XSP.fireEvent(evt, clientId, targetId, clientSideScriptName, submit, valmode, execId)
>   Allows to trigger an event script

Who can show me how to use this method and explain me what every argument stands for ??
with examples if possible !!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI: `XSP.fireEvent` is one of several private XSp client side JavaScript functions in xspClientDojo.js.

The description of the method in [XPages Portable Command Guide](http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/store/xpages-portable-command-guide-a-compact-resource-to-9780132943055) says:

> "*Used internally by the XSP.attachEvent() function and others. This is
>   a private function.*"

Comment: OK, I use this method in ssjs using view.postScript() that works perfectly but inside a xe:dialog it is ignored.
Have you an explanation for that ?

Comment: You can read the source in uncompressed JS files. Internal functions are unsupported, in that issues arising from the usage are unlikely to be investigated by IBM. Also there is no guarantee that it will work as expected from release to release.